# select dropdown option with selenium (https://pilot.principal.com/)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I've tried

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='principal-primary-navbar']/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[3]/a")).click();
```

but it doesn't click on the particular login button so I tried to click on PERSONAL which has the xpath as below,

```
//*[@id="principal-primary-navbar"]/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[3]/a
```

Comment: Can't get to the site from the US. Post the relevant HTML and format it. Also, format the code you have posted. See the formatting help if you need assistance.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response, really appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

I cannot access the pilot.principal.com but I can access principal.com. What I see on the page is a toggle menu. So you have to toggle the menu first and then click the item in the menu. See code below.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='principal-primary-navbar']/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a")).click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5); 
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='principal-primary-navbar']/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[3]/a")));
element.click();
```

Comment: Thanks so much Buaban, I tried your code, however it doesn't click on the particular drop down.

Comment: @Bhanu Can you add the relevant HTML in your question?